# Ruby Gems Problem: uninitialized constant Gem::GemRunner

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I had a rails 2.2 app running, when I tried to add the latest rspec plugin to it. I did that checking it from github with the script/plugin install command. That made some rake task to stop working, I googled for a while and found that I had to upgrade RubyGems. I did that and got the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Gem::GemRunner
```

It was a small and simple app under version control, so I erased everything, and apt-get remove ruby and rubygems, and reinstalled everything once again (doing apt-get install ruby, rubygems)

The problem it's still there, and I can't figure how to solve it. I'm quite new with Ubuntu, so maybe I'm not removing the packages really? (it takes very little time to execute the apt-get removes, so I'm not very confident)

What am I doing wrong? Is that a good way to do a 'clean start' (removing via apt and then reinstalling?)

PS: I've [read](http://soyunperdedor.com/node/13) that the problem is solved by modifiing framework.rb, but I cant find that file in the location that the author states...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a [blog post](http://ryanbigg.com/2008/04/unintialized-constant-gemgemrunner/) that solves this issue.

It's because it's still trying to use the old gem executable, so you just symbolically link the new one (gem1.8) in place of the old one.